# SML Case matching multiple conditions

Tags: c, switch-statement, sml

I have some SML code trying to match for specific strings for a project but I can't get this case statement to work (previously had if statements but after 3 it was going to be too messy).

```
case op_name of 
  "pair" => print "some pair"
| "equal" | "member" | "union" => print "some operation"
| _ => print "failed"
```

Currently I'm getting an error `Error: syntax error: replacing  BAR with  DARROW` on the second-last line after the | but  I can't find any reference of this sort of Case in SML so I was just trying something I imagined could work.
I'm trying to essentially get the equivalent of C code

```
switch(input) {
  case 5: 
    printf("some pair"); 
    break;
  case 6:
  case 7: 
  case 8:
    printf("some operation");
    break;
  default: printf("failed");
```

Comment: I've marked this question as a duplicate, but let me know if the linked answer does not satisfy you.

Comment: BTW, your attempt would work with SML/NJ if you wrap the three cases inside parantheses: `| ("equal" | "member" | "union") =>`.

Comment: Thank you very much, that answer was what I needed. I searched a bunch but I couldn't find that question either when I wrote it or when I was Googling and yeah your suggestion did work, thank you :)